# Django Model Auto Increment Primary Key Based on Foreign Key

Tags: python, mysql, django, model

I'm trying to figure out how to lay out two of my Django models so that when a new model is saved to the database, its primary key is incremented such that it is the next highest value for all records with the same foreign key.

It's much like [this question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605085/mysql-auto-increment-based-on-foreign-key), but I'm wondering how you would do it in Django. Here's an excerpt from the question which demonstrates a similar situation:

```
id | job_id | title
0     1        hi
1     1        hello
2     1        goodbye
0     2        hi
1     2        hello
```

I know [you can't have multiple primary keys in a Django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#do-django-models-support-multiple-column-primary-keys) and you can use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together), but the documentation says it uses the equivalent `UNIQUE` statement in the `CREATE` statements. Would

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   key = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key = True)
   fk = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

   def Meta(self):
      unique_together = ("key", "fk")
```

in the models work with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605386/451093) to accomplish what I'm looking for? The relationship between the models is one `ModelA` having many `ModelB`s, but each `ModelB` having only one `ModelA`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to make some changes to the model (if possible). So, `ModelA` should look something like this

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    key = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    fk = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

    def Meta(self):
        unique_together = ("key", "fk")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key = cal_key(self.fk)
        self.key = key
        super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As, you can see, I have **overridden the default [`save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save)** to calculate the key value in a `cal_key` function that takes `fk` as an argument. So, define the `cal_key` function in the models file.

```
def cal_key(fk):
    present_keys = ModelA.objects.filter(fk=fk).order_by('-key').values_list('key', flat=True)
    if present_keys:
        return present_keys[0]+1
    else:
        return 0
```

The `cal_key` function clearly indicates what you actually require.

Comment: Thanks Sandip. I went with your answer because it was more portable than Ignacio's answer.

Comment: If your application is multi-thread, is it possible that this solution can raise the unique_together validation error because it tries to allocate the same key to two different features, if they are saved in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Jason Ennio's answer will not let you update the model, since the super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs) is being controlled by the 'if' statement.

Updated 'save' method (indentation) to prevent the model from updating the 'key' every time you make an update:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
key = models.PositiveIntegerField()
fk = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

def Meta(self):
    unique_together = ("key", "fk")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self._state.adding is True:
        key = cal_key(self.fk)
        self.key = key
        super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```