# Create Concat Trigger in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've drawn a blank. (Ran out of Caffeine). I'm trying to create a Trigger in Phpmyadmin that will add two characters "MR" into each row. I don't want the characters added to the primary id but in a column labeled mer_sku. Also other data will be added into this mer_sku col from a html form so the data needs to be concat.

*Just to clarify, Im trying to make the trigger within the PHPmyadmin GUI*

Thanks!

**FORGOT TO ADD WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

[image]

**ERROR IS ON LINE 1**

[image]

Comment: yes. I forgot to add the screenshot. :(

Comment: `SET NEW.mer_sku = CONCAT(NEW.mer_sku, 'MR')`

Comment: thanks for this. However, I get a syntax error code. #1064? Not sure where the syntax error is.

Comment: You have `;` at the end of the line?

Comment: The error message should tell you where the syntax error is.

Comment: I've updated my POST. See the updated image.

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Note that the error message repeats the phrase `FOR EACH ROW`.  Perhaps the GUI inserts that automatically?  Try removing it from the GUI Definition field, leaving the `BEGIN...END` block.

Answer (score 1):

So let post my code first and then i'll explain my motivation and another issue that has presented itself that i'm trying to resolve.

```
?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $mfr   = $_POST['mfr'];
    $type  = $_POST['type'];
    $desc  = $_POST['description'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $qty   = $_POST['qty'];

    $last_id = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT m_id FROM merchandise";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $last_id = $row["m_id"];
    }
    $next_id = $last_id+1;
    $conc = number_format($next_id/100,2,'-','');

    $query = "INSERT INTO merchandise (mfr,type,description,mer_sku,price,qty) ";
    $query .="VALUES ('$mfr','$type','$desc','MR{$mfr}{$conc}','$price','$qty')";
    $add_sku_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirmQuery($add_sku_query);
    $alert = <<<DELIMETER

<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in' role='alert'>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<strong>Inventory Updated!</strong> <a href='inventory.php?view_all_inventory'>View All Inventory</a>
</div>
DELIMETER;

    echo $alert;
    }
?>
```

So first off let me point out that I did try to set this up using PDO but i'm not yet fully comprehending it so i'm sticking with mysqli. Which i know that how I have the code setup it leaves it vulnerable to SQL Injection.

So that aside, My motivation was to try and add items into a table sequentially. However, my code currently auto increments without regards to the $mfr variable which is ESSENTIAL. Each manufacturer has a unique value and so the auto increment would NEED to auto increment PER manufacturer instead of auto increment while disregarding the the manufacturer variable that is concatenated.

```
**CURRENT AUTO INCREMENT, [NOT WHAT I WHAT]**
MR500-01
MR600-02
MR700-03
MR500-04
MR600-05
MR700-06

**IDEAL AUTO INCREMENT, [WHAT I WANT]**
MR500-01
MR600-01
MR700-01
MR500-02
MR600-02
MR700-02
```

I hope I explained my thought. Anyways, this is my current status and I'm working towards creating the resolution that I NEEED.

Hope this was somewhat helpful to anyone or if someone has some helpful input that would be great and much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I found this question that is similar. However, this is using a MyISAM DB engine and  to autoincrement the primary key which I don't want to do. So based on the linked question. The result i'm looking for is close to this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605085/mysql-auto-increment-based-on-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GUI, try running it in the query section.
I think the error is because mysql treats `;`  as the end of your trigger declaration.

So redefine delimiter before writing code for the trigger

Try the below code

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER `merch_label` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `merchandise` 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    SET NEW.mer_sku = CONCAT(NEW.mer_sku, 'MR'); 
END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: this does not work still. I'm continuing to get an error. Unrecognized statement type. (near "BEFORE" at position 29)

Comment: Or I will get this error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8

Comment: The Trigger function didn't work however. I made some changes and I was able to get my code to work. During this process i discovered another issue. I'll update this post