# Getting id generated in a trigger for further requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, innodb

I have a table with two columns:

- caseId, referring to a foreign table column
- caseEventId, int, **unique** for a given caseId, which I want to **auto-increment for the same caseId**.

I know that the auto-increment option based on another column is not available in **mySql** with **InnoDb**:

[MySQL Auto Increment Based on Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605085/mysql-auto-increment-based-on-foreign-key)

[MySQL second auto increment field based on foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786665/mysql-second-auto-increment-field-based-on-foreign-key)

So I generate caseEventId into a trigger. My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.caseEvent (
  `caseId` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `caseEventId` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`caseId`, `caseEventId`),
  # Foreign key definition, not important here.
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And my trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `mydb`.`caseEvent_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `caseEvent` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(caseEventId) + 1 FROM caseEvent WHERE caseId = NEW.caseId),0)
        INTO @newCaseEventId;
    SET NEW.`caseEventId` = @newCaseEventId;
END
```

With this, I get my caseEventId which auto-increments.

However I need to re-use this new caseEventId in further calls within my INSERT transaction, so I place this id into @newCaseEventId within the trigger, and use it in following instructions:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mydb.caseEvent (caseId) VALUES ('fziNw6muQ20VGYwYPW1b');
SELECT @newCaseEventId;
# Do stuff based on @newCaseEventId
COMMIT;
```

This seems to work just fine but... what about concurrency, using connection pools etc...?

Is this @newCaseEventId variable going to be shared with all clients using the same connection, can I run into problems when my client server launches two concurrent transactions? This is using mysql under nodejs.

Is this safe, or is there a safer way to go about this? Thanks.

---

**Edit 2020/09/24**

FYI I have dropped this approach altogether. I was trying to use the db in a way it isn't meant to be used.

Basically I have dropped caseEventId, and any index which is supposed to increment nicely based on a given column value.

I rely instead on properly written queries on the read side, when I retrieve data, to recreate my caseEventId field...

Comment: You create a race condition by doing this. In other words, what if two concurrent sessions INSERT at the same time? They will both read the same value for `max(caseEventId)+1`. Ultimately, there's no way you can implement auto-increment per `caseId` except by locking the table.

Comment: @Bill Karwin  That's in part what I'm worried about. If you have guidelines in how to implement the table lock without creating a potential deadlock, I'm interested!

Comment: [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) would do it. Most people avoid this because it severely limits throughput if your app needs to do a high rate of queries concurrently on the table. But if you have a low rate of queries, it can work.

Comment: The other more common solution is to forget about numbering your caseEvent independently per caseId. Just use an auto-increment.

Answer (score 1):

That is no problem, the user defined variables a per client.

That means every user has its own use defined varoables

> User-defined variables are session specific. A user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. (Exception: A user with access to the Performance Schema user_variables_by_thread table can see all user variables for all sessions.) All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.
> [see manul](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: My client is a nodejs / express server. It will handle multiple requests in parallel, and launch concurrent mySql queries. These queries coming from the same server, will they be considered as coming from the same client? I'm still fuzzy on how connections are handled.

Comment: you must have somewhere a connect and you close that connection( i hope) or have you one connection and send all rquest through there?

Comment: Yes, I open and close connection for each transaction, so based on your reaction, I guess I'm ok. What is left then is Bill Karwin's remark, and the need to lock tables to avoid race conditions. Thanks!

Comment: yes lockng the table is one possibilirty amking the colun UNIQUE is another. there is a good caise, why auto_increment is baried in mysql and works, doing that all in your app os hard word and if you only need numbers unnecesssary.